# Equivalence relation proof. If a ~ b then [a] = [b]

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I want to prove that if $a \sim b$ then $[a] = [b]$ (the set of a equals the set of b). I know that in order to prove this I must show that $[a] \subset [b]$ and $[b] \subset [a]$. How should the proof look?

Comment: Note that by symmetry, it's enough to prove that if $a \sim b$ then $[a] \subseteq [b]$; then just switch around $a$ and $b$ to get the other direction.

Comment: What you are to prove is that if $a \sim b$ then the equivalence class of a is equal to the equivalence class of b. It's that simple.  Of course, if the equivalence class of a is equal to the equivalence class of b, then we have that the equivalence class of b is equal to the equivalence class of a.  Hence $[a] = [b]$ and $[b] = [a].$   We're done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $x\in[a]$ we have xRa and since aRb therefore because of equivalence we have xRb therefore $x\in[b]$ and $[a]\subset[b]$. With the same argument you can show the inverse

Answer (score 1):

What this means is that if $x\in [a]$, then $x\in [b]$. In other words if $x\sim a$, then $x\sim b$ knowing that $a\sim b$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: I understand the point you are making, but I am still struggling to formulate the proof altogether.

Comment: $x\sim a$, $a\sim b$. What does that tell you?